# Why does '->'(12, b) give an error?

Tags: r

In R operators can also be expressed as a function call, e.g.

```
'<-'(b, 12)
```

for `b <- 12`.
Why does the following give an error:

```
'->'(12, b)
```

? (The code `12 -> b` works as expected.)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Because operators are "translated" to functions by the parser and both left and right assignment are parsed to the `<-` function. There is no right assignment function.

```
e <- quote(b <- 12)
as.list(e)
#[[1]]
#`<-`
#
#[[2]]
#b
#
#[[3]]
#[1] 12

e <- quote(12 -> b)
as.list(e)
#[[1]]
#`<-`
#
#[[2]]
#b
#
#[[3]]
#[1] 12
```